# How to create a function to lauch org-capture with a selected template?

Tags: org-capture

Let's say my capture template is bound to 't':

```
(defun my/captureTemplate ()
(interactive)
(org-capture "r")
```

This won't work as it will show me the whole list of potential templates to choose from. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't ask the same question in [two places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66115946/how-to-create-a-function-to-lauch-org-capture-with-a-selected-template)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
(defun my/captureTemplate ()
  (interactive)
  (org-capture nil "r"))
```

as `KEY` is the second optional argument to `org-capture`.

Comment: Thanks so much!